# Crystal Report with VB6

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal (v9) report with field definitions defined (and placed on the report).

On my vb6 form I dropped a crystal viewer object from the toolbox.

Not sure why but I am assuming that there is a way to programmatically bind record set data to these fields.

Is this possible?

Eg,

```
Report.Field1 = rs("Data")
Report.Field2 = rs("Data2")
```

I believe I am using `CRAXDRT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically alter the data connection, set parameters and even alter the selection criteria but I don’t think you can set the data on fields manually. Data has to come from the selection statement w/i the report itself. It has no DOM, per se.

Looks like you can use the report viewer to set a whole reports data source to a ado recordset at runtime (I didn't think you could), but not one field/control at a time.

[Ways to feed a report (degined by crystal reports 8.5 in vb6.0) to show a special record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286587/ways-to-feed-a-report-degined-by-crystal-reports-8-5-in-vb6-0-to-show-a-specia)

Comment: Thanks. How do I display the recordset data on the crystal viewer - in other words - if I just pass the recordset how does crystal figure out where to put what data?

Comment: textboxes/controls in the report are are "bound" to a certain database fields or crystal functions. to change the binding you have to edit the report in Crystal reports 9 or >

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to Crystal so am having trouble understanding - the fields from my ado recordset are not available in the actual database so how are the controls in the report bound to them? (because the data comes from the ado record set that is generated in code)